# Let $A$ and $B$ be real matrix such that $A+iB$ is non singular show that there exist $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A+tB$ is non singular

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be real matrices, with $A+iB$ non-singular. I need to show that there exist a real number $t$ such that $ A+tB $ is non-singular.

I don't have any idea how I can approach this question... could I please get a hint?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I [don't believe](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) that you don't have any idea. You know more than you think. The question asks about non-singular matrices. What do you know about those? How would you most easily tell whether a matrix is singular or not? Have you tried to apply that here?

Comment: $p(t)=det(A+tB)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients. It is a non-zero polynomial, because $p(i)\neq0$. Therefore, it cannot be zero for all values of $t$.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft / That is, it cannot be $0$ for all real $t$.

Comment: I wonder if there is a geometric proof of this?